# Is there a way to let arguments be var instead of val?

Tags: scala, command-line-arguments, method-parameters

When debugging command line argument handling in Java I'm used to doing

```
args = new String[] { "some", "new", "arguments" };
```

(especially useful if have a filename as argument which you frequently change, but don't want to go through some dialog windows in the IDE). This has the benefit that I can simply comment out the line when building a release.

So when I tried this in Scala I discovered that arguments are `val`s. (And I can't write `var` in front of the parameter).

- **Q1**: What's the rationale for this?
- **Q2**: So is there any obvious work-around except for doing

  ```
  val newArgs = if (...) args else Array("some", "new", "arguments")
  ```

  and stick to `newArgs` in the remaining main method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Q1:** Mutating the input parameters is often seen as bad style and makes it harder to reason about code.

**Q2:** You could assign the `args` to a `var` before doing anything with it.

Comment: Q1, good point. Q2, yes. That's better than the if-line, because then I can simply comment out the reassignment as in the case of Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are mutable, so if you insist:

```
Seq("some", "new", "arguments").copyToArray(args, 0, 3)
```

That does, of course, only work if there is enough space in the passed array.

<strike>Remember that you can use default parameters in Scala to solve your original probem in a much cleaner way.</strike>

Comment: Could you give an example of such default parameter for the main method?

Comment: Ah, sorry, got carried away there. Does not work since in case of no parameters, an empty array is passed. Maybe that might be worth a change.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify the args inside of the function, then your approach in the description is enough.

However, if you need to treat it as a true "reference" type and keep the modifications valid outside the function, you can wrap the arguments in a case class, e.g.:

```
case class Ref[A](var value: A)
```

And use it like:

```
def modify(refInt: Ref[Int]) = refInt.value = 3
```

Then, when you use `refInt.value` outside the function, it would still be 3.